# MySql Communications link failure

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I connected to mysql server with specifying database (`jdbc:mysql://hostname:port/db`) or without specifying database (`jdbc:mysql://hostname:port/`)using DataGrip in all networks.

While I am in the school network, I can still connect to mysql server without specifying database, or with specifying database except X database. If I specify X database like `jdbc:mysql://hostname:port/X`, take the following error:

`[08S01] Communications link failure.
The last packet successfully received from the server was 8 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 8 milliseconds ago.`

I tried to connect with specifying timeout variables,I did not get any result.
Anyone suggest me the correct way to solve this issue.

> Full Exception stacktrace:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 200 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 24 milliseconds ago.
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1116)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3589)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3478)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4019)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:951)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1717)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1276)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2395)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2428)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2213)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:797)
at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:389)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:305)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
at Example.main(Example.java:22)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.fill(ReadAheadInputStream.java:114)
at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.readFromUnderlyingStreamIfNecessary(ReadAheadInputStream.java:161)
at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.read(ReadAheadInputStream.java:189)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:3036)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3489)
... 20 more
```

Comment: Please post the full exception stacktrace, the exception cause usually provides a clue as to the underlying reason.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Solving a "communications link failure" with JDBC and MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865538/solving-a-communications-link-failure-with-jdbc-and-mysql)

Comment: I tried all of the suggestions, but it is not resolved. I created 2 test databases, it connects X database, does not connect Y database.